# remove parent not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am practicing jquery , by appending an removing input ,i succeded appending in input field but not been able to remove appended input field.
i am also confused with parent() in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.ancestors * { 
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid lightgrey;
    color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 15px;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#add').click(

function(){
$('#a').append('<div><input type="text"  name="ingre[]"><button class="remo">remove</button></div>');

});



});

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".remo").click(function(){
//alert('ok');
$(this).parent('.remo').remove();

});
});
</script>
</head>

<body class="ancestors">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id='a'>
<input type="text" >

</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing will not work, as you are attaching the event to all current elements that exist with the class `.remo`. When you click Add a new element is created that does not have the handler bound, so it will not remove anything. The solution for this is event delegation, replace this:

```
$(".remo").click(function(){
    $(this).parent('.remo').remove();
});
```

With this:

```
$("#a").on('click', '.remo', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: can you please explain $(this).closest('div')

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#a').append('<div><input type="text"  name="arr[]"><button class="remo">remove</button></div>');
    });

    $('#a').on('click', '.remo', function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ancestors">
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div id='a'>
<input type="text" >

</div>
```

---